# Different result solving differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I'm trying to solve this differential equation. 
But I get a different result when I solve it with Maple. What am I missing?
[image: Maples Result]
[image: My equation]

Comment: I think it must be $$\exp(\cos(t))$$

Comment: You replace only the integral as second factor with $(\frac{t^8}8+k)$, so the first factor also applies to the constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $e^{-P(t)} = e^{-(-7\cos t)} = e^{7\cos t}$.  You dropped the minus in the 7th line.