# I need help solving the differential equation $y'(t)+7\sin(t)y(t)=(te^{\cos(t)})^{7}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I need help solving this differential equation

$$y'(t)+7\sin(t)y(t)=(te^{\cos(t)})^{7}$$

What I've tried:

$$\implies e^{-\cos(t)}y'(t)+e^{-7\cos(t)}7\sin(t)y(t)=t^{7}$$
$$\implies (y(t)e^{-7\cos(t)})'=t^7$$
$$\implies y(t)e^{-7\cos(t)}=\int t^7 dt = \frac{t^8}{8}+c$$
$$\implies y(t)=\frac{e^{7\cos(t)}t^8}{8}+c$$

However, when I use Maple's dsolve I get a different result. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: Instead of $e{…}$ you must write $$\exp{…}$$ in Maple

Comment: I just tried using dsolve replacing $e^{7cos(t)}$ with exp(cos(t))^7 and I got the same result.

Comment: If your look at other questions with the `maple` tag on this site you'll find the essentially same question asked two hours before yours.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977582/different-result-solving-differential-equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to multiply the constant C by $\exp(7cos(t))$ on your result.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't see that.